# Is there a Perl equivalent for String.scan found in Ruby?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to do this in Perl:

```
>> "foo bar baz".scan /(\w+)/
=> [["foo"], ["bar"], ["baz"]]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is intended to accomodate a general regular expression, separated by arbitrary other characters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This does essentially the same thing.

```
my @elem = "foo bar baz" =~ /(\w+)/g
```

You can also set the "default scalar" variable `$_`.

```
$_ = "foo bar baz";
my @elem = /(\w+)/g;
```

See [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more information.

---

If you only want to use that string as an array, you could use `qw()`.

```
my @elem = qw"foo bar baz";
```

See [`perldoc perlop` ​ ​( Quote and Quote-like Operators )](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Comment: IMHO, explicit assignment to `$_` merely to use one of Perl's *implicit* `$_` idioms awkwardly misses the point of that idiomatic shorthand.

Comment: I know, I want to expand on that part of the answer, to show where it would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Also, split, e.g.,

```
my $x = "foo bar baz";
my @elem = split(' ', $x);
```

OR

```
my @elem = split(/\w+/, $x);
```

etc.

Comment: I think you mean "`split /(\w+)/` ..."

Comment: `split ' ', $x` is unsatisfactory if there may be `\W` characters (other than `\s`) in the string. `split /(\w+)/, $x` will give you `('', 'foo', ' ', 'bar', ' ', 'baz')` making this a pointless exercise.

Comment: Sinan is right, I looked at using split and it isn't right for this purpose.  I just want an array of elements matching the regex.

Comment: You're correct that split(' ',...) is unsatisfactory in more complex cases.  It will work for the trivial case presented.

Thanks for catching the gaff on split(/\w+/).  I'm the complement of the OP, where I don't know Ruby but know perl, and misunderstood scan's functionality.

Comment: split /\W+/, 'foo bar baz' gives 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' as requested

Comment: but is it always going to be that easy to invert the regular expression for use in split()?

Comment: I think that, based on a better understanding of ruby's scan() method, that perl's split is not the appropriate choice.  split and scan are opposites, and I shouldn't have brought up split in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

They key perl concept is scalar vs list context. Assigning an expression to an array forces list context, as does something like a while loop.

Thus, the equivalent of the block form of String#scan is to use the regexp with a while loop:

```
while ("foo bar baz" =~ /(\w+)/) {
    my $word = $1;
    do_something_with($word);
}
```